# get PythonManager working in Toon Boom Harmony v20

Tags: python

I am unable to get the PythonManager class working for **Toon Boom Harmony v20 (20.0.4)**

According to the documentation the [PythonManager class](https://docs.toonboom.com/help/harmony-20/scripting/extended/module-PythonManager.html) should be available with the Harmony v20 installation.

When launching Harmony I get the following in the command line output:

```
Python not detected, python script will be disabled.
```

[image: Harmony launch command line output]

I have Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 installed on my machine with My environment variables containing:

```
C:\Python39\Scripts\
C:\Python39\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Toon Boom Animation\Toon Boom Harmony 20 Premium\win64\bin
```

I have uninstalled all previous Harmony versions on my machine to perform a clean install of  Harmony v20.0.4

**PythonManager** is also unavailable when right clicking within the **ScriptManager** window ( where it displays all available classes/methods from that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by updating Python to version [2.7.15](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2715/)

The Python version was 2.7.9 when I was experiencing the error.

I encountered this problem again After Upgrading to [Harmony 22.0.1](https://docs.toonboom.com/help/harmony-22/premium/release-notes/harmony/harmony-22-0-1-release-notes.html#:%7E:text=Harmony%2022.0.1%20Release%20Notes%20Harmony%2022.0.1%20build%2022.0.1.19025,this%20release%20of%20Harmony%20and%20later.%20Drawing%20Tools) which uses **Python 3.9**

To solve this, using **Command Prompt** I made sure that the system path was loading with:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert( 0, r"C:/Program Files (x86)/Toon Boom Animation/Toon Boom Harmony 22 Premium/win64/bin/python-packages" )
```

And then extended the DLL path with:

```py
import os
os.add_dll_directory( "C:/Program Files (x86)/Toon Boom Animation/Toon Boom Harmony 22 Premium/win64/bin" )
os.add_dll_directory( "C:/Program Files (x86)/Toon Boom Animation/Toon Boom Harmony 22 Premium/win64/bin/python-packages/PySide6" )
```

and then checked the libraries were loading without error:

```py
import PySide6 
from PySide6 import QtCore 
import ToonBoom
from ToonBoom import harmony
```

before launching a scene using the **harmony** class

```py
pathToHarmonyProject = "C:/EXAMPLE_FOLDER/HARMONY_SCENE.xstage"
harmony.open_project(pathToHarmonyProject)
```

(all of this code is within the same Command Prompt session)